# Layout breaks on browser resize

Tags: html, css

Got a weird problem,i.e,**Layout of webpage breaks** on resize of the browser/when accessed through mobile device/when switched to lower resolution ( 800*600 / 1024*768 )

Temporary link : http://krishnaspirit.hostoi.com/

P.S : Its a **full-width website** & Works fine on **1366*768**.

CSS :

```
    * { padding:0px; margin:0px; }
    p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,a{ font-family: 'Armata', sans-serif; }

    /*header*/

    .header {  z-index:5000; position:fixed; top:0px; width:100%;  min-width:960px; height:100px; background-color:#4E4E56;}
    .header #nav li:last-child { margin-right:0px; }
    .header #nav li {  transition:1s ease all;line-height:40px; 
    display:inline-block; margin-right:3px; width:116px; height:40px;text-align:center; border-radius:5px;}
    .header #nav li a {  font-size:15px; color:#DCD0C0; display:block; height:100%; text-decoration:none; }
    .header #nav li:hover {  background-color: #DA635D; }
    .header #nav li a:hover { color:#fff; }
    .header #nav  {  position:absolute; right:10px; top:35px; width:600px; }
    .current {background-color: #DA635D; cursor:none;}
    .header #nav .current a { color:#fff; }
    .header .logo img {width:100px; height:95px;  position:absolute; top:5px; left:12px; line-height:100px; font-size:40px; color:#fff;}
    .header .logo .name { font-size:40px; color:#ccc; 
    font-family: 'Armata', sans-serif; position:absolute; left:110px;top:29px; }

    /*sub-head*/
    .sub-header .top-logo { float:left; }
    .sub-header .top-name { float:right; font-size:30px; padding-top:120px; color:#003366; } 
    .sub-header {  width:85%; text-align:center; margin:150px auto; }


    /*main-body*/
    .content  { float:left; }
    .news { float:right; margin-right:5px; }
    .news {   box-shadow:3px 3px 5px #ccc; padding:0px;  border-radius:3px; }
    .news p { font-weight:bold; font-size:15px; padding-bottom:20px;}
    .news {  border:1px solid #ccc; width:27%;  min-width:27%; padding:5px; height:300px;}
    .news .news_body { padding:3px; text-align:center;}
    .content { box-shadow:3px 3px 5px 0px #ccc; width:70%; height:300px; border-radius:3px; margin-left:5px; border:1px solid #ccc; font-size:15px;  padding:5px;}
    .content .sub-main { margin-top:15px;  text-align:justify; padding:10px; }
    .content #myMenu { width:100%; text-align:center; height:30px;  }
    .content #myMenu{ list-style-type:none; }
    .content #myMenu li {  border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; color:#999; display:inline-block; width:30%; line-height:30px;}
    .content #myMenu li:hover { font-weight:bold; }
    .content #myMenu li a {   display:block; width:100%;  }
    .content #myMenu li a:hover {  border-bottom:5px solid #DA635D; color:#DA635D;  cursor:pointer;}

    .body_wrapper { margin-bottom:500px; margin-top:70px; background-color:#ccc; }

    /*footer*/
    footer { width:100%; height:50px; line-height:50px; background-color:#4E4E56; }
    footer p  a{  color:#DA635D; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold;}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you are using `percentage` in your `divs`? Since this kind of layout is `fluid`. Coz if your layout is `fixed` you will set your `divs` to `px` instead of `percentage`. And `percentage` may cause you to break your layout when re-sized. Use @aniskhan001 advice below. :)

Comment: But for a full width website what can be the pixel value for each div?

Comment: Well, it depends on your clients available screen width. For example here in philippines, the lowest screen resolution that a client may have is about 1024px, I think. So I can set my fixed layout to about 980px. That's actually the standard `fixed layout` that I am using.

Comment: Just a note on `fixed layout`. Unlike `fluid` ones, your may not enjoy a full width layout though :)

Comment: ya I agree with your point.. but how can I make this current site have fixed layout if I go with pixel values?

Comment: Well changing your layout from `fluid` to `fixed` is just like you're starting from beginning. Just try to set `px` to the `divs` instead of `percentage`. Coz your header is fine, just the `divs` below that are breaking.

Comment: I did the same thing but providing pixels to a div in terms of resolution, outputs different at different resolution. suppose I specify width of 1000px to a div in 1024 of reso .. the same div gets a blank white space on right side in 1360 of reso.how to overcome such problem? 

If possible please respecify the width of body_wrapper div and its content in terms of pixels.

Sorry to trouble you but need help.

Comment: I downloaded your page and works fine on me when I change the `.body_wrapper` width into a `px`. I guess you need to set max-width in that `class`. Don't follow the width of browser so it won't break. I'd tried  it and it works. Hope it will work on you now :)

Comment: will you please reply with code you have made changes to.I didnt get your solution properly.

Comment: I'd sent it to your facebook account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a weird problem. You need to use **@media query** to fix the problem.

The image on left side is large enough to occupy almost half of total screen width at a resolution *1024x768*. You need to define style sheet on different screens using media query.

**Example -**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
    .main .sub-header .top-logo{
        width: 250px;
    }

    .main .sub-header .top-logo img{
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

This snippet will only take action in device screen width less than or equal to `1024px`.

As you can see, for this type of device resolution I have reduced the width of `.top-logo` to make sure it can fit properly in small screen. You need to define `.top-name` and other elements accordingly to fit them properly for different device width. Hope you get the idea.

Comment: I appreciate your reply, I knew the media query stuff but wanted to avoid it.any other way ? I actually want a fixed layout for all of the screens irrespective of resolution ( I want a fixed layout rather than responsive/fluid )

Comment: Fixed layout is **FIXED**. Which means the properties (e.g. width, height, colors etc) will always be same regardless of any device widths/screens. If you want **fixed layout** then the properties will not vary and you will again get that broken layout.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing causing this problem is when one `@media` query has a missing closing brace **}**.

For example if your CSS has something like:

```
nav {
    position: relative;
    width: 95%;
    margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: var(--magnolia);
    font-family: Roboto;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 860px) {
    nav {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
<----------------- /* A closing brace "}" is missing here !  */

.navbar {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    height: auto;
}
etc.
etc.
```

This makes all CSS below it revert to default, e.g. width: 100%.
Overflow abounds in such a situation.

Since W3C CSS Validator may not detect this, you have to closely read through all `@media` queries before the breaking elements looking for missing closing braces. Just one of these can screw up everything below that part of the web page. Fix it and everything is suddenly fine.